# SVN monitor like tool for clear case

Tags: svn, clearcase

Is there any software for clear case VOB's available for monitoring the commits, like svn monitor do for subversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about this [SVN Monitor](http://www.vercue.com/), then there isn't a tool which will query the server for displaying in advance what could need to be updated or would result in a merge conflict.

All those state are resolved only upon view update or merge itself.